# SQL Server: How to extract specific bit from byte in binary or varbinary value

Tags: sql-server, bit-manipulation, bit

I have varbinary value, I want to extract first 3 bits of 0th byte and
value is 0x4D79205465737420537472696E67.

Thank You,

Answer (score 11):

This extracts 3 bits from the first byte of the `varbinary` value:

```
select CONVERT(tinyint,0x7) & SUBSTRING(0x4D79205465737420537472696E67,1,1)
```

The logic being that on the left hand side of the AND (`&`), we have a byte with 3 bits set. On the right hand side, we extract a single byte from the `varbinary` ([`SUBSTRING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) is 1 based rather than 0 based, so this is the first byte).

To extract the last 5 bits from the 3rd byte, we'd have:

```
select CONVERT(tinyint,0xF8) & SUBSTRING(0x4D79205465737420537472696E67,3,1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do substring on a varbinary? If so, each byte counts as a single char?

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez - I linked to the documentation for it. I wouldn't say each byte counts as a char. Instead, it's explicitly defined in terms of bytes rather than chars: "The values for *start* and *length* must be specified in number of characters for ntext, char, or varchar data types and bytes for text, image, binary, or varbinary data types."

Comment: I was trying UDF as follows:

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetByte]
(
 BinaryData varbinary(MAX),
 ByteIndex int,
 Index int
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
 --declare BinaryColumn binary(5)
 --set BinaryColumn = convert(binary,BinaryData)
 
 declare Ret varchar(20)
 select Ret= SUBSTRING(BinaryData, ByteIndex, 1)
 RETURN  Ret

END

Comment: The docco suggests what you've done is right, but trying the second select (5 bits of 3rd byte) returns 0.

Comment: @NeilMoss - that's because I'm a muppet and forgot that I was meant to be specifying the constant in hex rather than decimal. Corrected the constant now (and actually run it).